# What are all the possible ways for a Windows UWP app relaunch?

Tags: angular, windows, cordova, ionic-framework, uwp

Got a Windows UWP application built using ionic/angular/cordova stack. For some reason the app is automatically getting closed is what we hear from the users. From code, we don't do anything like closing the application. During this instance there is no Event View log for this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Having an error monitoring library like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) would be great for these types of issues. It will be difficult to help you out with no other details of the error. Your best bet is to get a debug version of the app and open the inspector to see what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Noting that your program may be closed due to an unhandled error in the program,you can try to avoid the program closing by [handling UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception?view=winrt-22621) first.

If you need the restart function, you can use the [CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.requestrestartasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-applicationmodel-core-coreapplication-requestrestartasync(system-string)). The system suspends your app When ao is minimized or in the background.So, the app must be visible and foreground when it calls `RequestRestartAsync`.

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
}

private void App_UnhandledException(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{ 
    //handle exception
    e.Handled= true;
}
```

---

This is a sample code for restarting the app.
If restart request is denied, a toast will be sent to tell the user to restart manually.

```
AppRestartFailureReason result = await CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync("Application Restart");

if (result == AppRestartFailureReason.NotInForeground
    || result == AppRestartFailureReason.Other)
{
    // Requires Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications NuGet package version 7.0 or greater
    new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
    .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
    .AddText("This UWP Restart failed")
    .AddText("Please manually restart.")
    .Show();
}
```